# More Robust Form of Excel Cell Referencing

Tags: excel, reference, cell

I often use cell referencing for single use or nearly entire sheets. I can not find a way to do cell referencing which transposes cell format (bold, italics, cell fill, etc.) along with the context.

EDIT: Summary I am trying to get one cell which references another cell in another worksheet to also reflect changes in format (bold, cell fill, etc.) and not just value

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55540396/edit) to provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad i'm not sure how to display that data.. I just want one cell that references another cell in another worksheet to also reflect changes in format (bold, cell fill, etc.) and not just value

Comment: There is no straightforward way of doing that. You could try doing all formatting using Styles, or try to track all changes using VBA.

Comment: Paste special > As linked picture. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not super robust but paste as linked picture does what you want:

[image]

Comment: no this is great.. the issue is that it limits how many cells i can include in each linked picture.. it's workable though, for now